# Unable to attach to the process VS2019 / Win10

Tags: c#, windows-10, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

**Error Message**

```
Unable to attach to the process. Visual Studio has insufficient privileges to debug this process. To debug this process, Visual Studio must be run as an administrator.
```

**Explanation**

I use Visual Studio 2019 on a Windows 10 maschine

and installed via PowerShell de Service and start the service.

PowerShell command was:

```
New-Service -Name "ServiceName" -BinaryPathName D:\Project\ServiceName.exe
```

I try also with credentials:

```
$credential = Get-Credential    --> Enter credentials
New-Service -Name "ServiceName" -BinaryPathName D:\Project\ServiceName.exe -Credential $credential
```

But if I try to attach the Service into Visual Studio 2019 (Run as an administrator) I get the message "Unable to attach..." (see ErrorMessage)

If I installed the service without credentials, I see the entry *SYSTEM* in the column username in Visual Studio. And with credentials *DOMAINNAME\username [administrator]*

Why is [administrator] appended at the end?

Do I not have enough rigths on my maschine?

I work on a virtual maschine Windows 10 environment.

**Other Settings**

Configuration:
Local Security Policy --> Logal Policies/User Rights Assignment/Debug programs --> set my Domain

Local Security Policy --> Local Policies/Network access: Sharing and security model for local accounts --> Classic

Try on Debug|AnyCPU and Debug|x86

Comment: It depands how you compile your code. Do not use "Any Debug"

Comment: @Jules_96 Why can't I use AnyCPU? What is the reason? --> The Windows set it automaticly to x86 process.

Comment: Did you actually run Visual Studio AS administrator? In the title bar for visual studio it will actually say "Microsoft Visual Studio (Administrator)" when running as administrator.

Comment: If you want to debug a program on a remote server, just run the debugger on the server. The debugger can be found in the VS installation directory, and the Remote Debugger file is copied to the server.

Comment: @LarryBud I run the VS2019 with administrator rights

Comment: @housheng The Service run on my development environment. I don't have a server/client environment.

Answer (score 1):

Our IT department found the mistake, it was in the Debug rigths (Local Security Policy/UserRightAssignment/Debug programs)

Now he added me as a user and now it works in the debug mode :-)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/debug-programs